# Can't get gridview dynamic label ID but textboxes are fine

Tags: c#, .net

Here is how i get the values from the gridview controllses, as you can see i do the same way for the label as the textbox, except all textboxes get value and label doesn't and i can't find anything different in the code. The function fillGrid() is just a skeleton for the table to fill it first before placing controllers on it

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                    {
                        var Column1TextBoxes = Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(k => k.Contains("lblIdDetComp")).ToList();   // Gridview Column 1
                        var Column2TextBoxes = Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(k => k.Contains("txtComponente")).ToList();  // Gridview Column 2
                        var Column3TextBoxes = Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(k => k.Contains("txtBase")).ToList();        // Gridview Column 3
                        var Column4TextBoxes = Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(k => k.Contains("txtComprimento")).ToList(); // Gridview Column 4

                        if (Request.Form[Column1TextBoxes[j]] != "") comp[j].ID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form[Column1TextBoxes[j]]); // Column1 values
                        else break;
                        if (Request.Form[Column2TextBoxes[j]] != "") comp[j].Nome = Request.Form[Column2TextBoxes[j]]; // Column2 values
                        else break;
                        if (Request.Form[Column3TextBoxes[j]] != "") comp[j].Base = Request.Form[Column3TextBoxes[j]]; // Column3 values
                        else break;
                        if (Request.Form[Column4TextBoxes[j]] != "") comp[j].Comprimento = Convert.ToDouble(Request.Form[Column4TextBoxes[j]]); // Column4 values
                        else break;
                        j++;
                    }
                }


private void fillGrid()
    {
        int rowCount = 0;

        if (ViewState["rowCount"] != null)
        {
            rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["rowCount"]);
        }

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("IdDetComp",typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Componente", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Base", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Comprimento", typeof(string));


        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add("","", "", "");
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        upDetComps.Update();
    }
```

This is where I add the information to the gridview

```
int i = 0;
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {                
            Componente[] Comp = (Componente[])ViewState["Componente"];

            if (i < Convert.ToInt32(txtNumComps.Text))
            {

                Label lblIdDetComp = new Label();
                lblIdDetComp.ID = "lblIdDetComp" + (i + 1).ToString();
                if (Comp[i] != null) lblIdDetComp.Text = Comp[i].ID.ToString();

                TextBox txtComponente = new TextBox();
                txtComponente.ID = "txtComponente" + (i + 1).ToString();
                if (Comp[i] != null) txtComponente.Text = Comp[i].Nome;                    

                TextBox txtBase = new TextBox();
                txtBase.ID = "txtBase" + (i + 1).ToString();
                if (Comp[i] != null) txtBase.Text = Comp[i].Base;

                TextBox txtComprimento = new TextBox();
                txtComprimento.ID = "txtComprimento" + (i + 1).ToString();

                if (Comp[i] != null)
                {
                    if (Comp[i].Comprimento != 0)
                        txtComprimento.Text = Comp[i].Comprimento.ToString();
                    else
                        txtComprimento.Text = "";
                }

                e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(lblIdDetComp);
                e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(txtComponente);
                e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(txtBase);
                e.Row.Cells[3].Controls.Add(txtComprimento);

                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just remove the condition and assign a hard-coded value to the label and see if that shows up.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be this is because by default, the [Label.AutoSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.label.autosize?view=netframework-4.7.2) property is `false`:

> **Property Value**
>
> **Boolean**
>
> `true` if the control adjusts its width to closely fit its contents; otherwise, `false`.
>
> When added to a form using the designer, the default value is `true`. When instantiated from code, the default value is `false`.

So the text is there, it's just size (0,0).

Try setting

```
lblIdDetComp.AutoSize = true;
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to recognize, i found out that the values appear if i use a textbox instead a label and remove the hidding property... The problem is that i don't want to show the ID colum, specially with textboxes